# Google Document AI Custom Extractor type object 'Property' has no attribute 'OccurenceType'

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I have a Google Document AI Custom Extractor model trained and it works great when I test it in the cloud console but I'm struggling to get a sample python program to work.

I've taken this sample code and added one of my custom field entity definitions (cancerType) to it but can't seem to get past this:

**An error occurred: type object 'Property' has no attribute 'OccurenceType'**

If I don't attempt to define an entity I get a 400 error complaining about a lack of schema.

| Name | Data type | Occurrence | Enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cancerType | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |
| mutatedGene | Plain text | Optional multiple | Yes |
| otherBiomarker | Plain text | Optional multiple | Yes |
| patientDOB | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |
| patientGender | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |
| patientName | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |
| reportDate | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |
| specimenDate | Plain text | Optional once | Yes |

```
from typing import Optional
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai_v1beta3 as documentai

project_id = "xxx"
location = "xxxx"
processor_id = "xxxx"
file_path = "report_f1.pdf"
mime_type = "application/pdf"
field_mask = "text,entities,pages.pageNumber"
processor_version_id = "xxxx"

def process_document_custom_extractor_sample(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    processor_version: str,
    file_path: str,
    mime_type: str,
) -> None:
    try:
        # Entities to extract
        properties = [
            documentai.DocumentSchema.EntityType.Property(
                name="cancerType",
                value_type="string",
                occurence_type=documentai.DocumentSchema.EntityType.Property.OccurenceType.OPTIONAL_ONCE,
            ),
            # Add other properties based on your requirements...
        ]

        # Optional: For Generative AI processors, request different fields than the
        # schema for a processor version
        process_options = documentai.ProcessOptions(
            schema_override=documentai.DocumentSchema(
                display_name="CDE Schema",
                description="Document Schema for the CDE Processor",
                entity_types=[
                    documentai.DocumentSchema.EntityType(
                        name="custom_extraction_document_type",
                        base_types=["document"],
                        properties=properties,
                    )
                ],
            )
        )

        # Online processing request to Document AI
        document = process_document(
            project_id,
            location,
            processor_id,
            processor_version,
            file_path,
            mime_type,
            process_options=process_options,
        )

        for entity in document.entities:
            print_entity(entity)
            # Print Nested Entities (if any)
            for prop in entity.properties:
                print_entity(prop)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

def print_entity(entity: documentai.Document.Entity) -> None:
    # Fields detected. For a full list of fields for each processor see
    # the processor documentation:
    # https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list
    key = entity.type_

    # Some other value formats in addition to text are availible
    # e.g. dates: `entity.normalized_value.date_value.year`
    text_value = entity.text_anchor.content
    confidence = entity.confidence
    normalized_value = entity.normalized_value.text
    print(f"    * {repr(key)}: {repr(text_value)}({confidence:.1%} confident)")

    if normalized_value:
        print(f"    * Normalized Value: {repr(normalized_value)}")

def process_document(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    processor_version: str,
    file_path: str,
    mime_type: str,
    process_options: Optional[documentai.ProcessOptions] = None,
) -> documentai.Document:
    try:
        # You must set the `api_endpoint` if you use a location other than "us".
        client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(
            client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")
        )

        # The full resource name of the processor version, e.g.:
        # `projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}/processorVersions/{processor_version_id}`
        # You must create a processor before running this sample.
        name = client.processor_version_path(
            project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version
        )

        # Read the file into memory
        with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
            image_content = image.read()

        # Configure the process request
        request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
            name=name,
            raw_document=documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type),
            # Only supported for Document OCR processor
            process_options=process_options,
        )

        result = client.process_document(request=request)

        # For a full list of `Document` object attributes, reference this page:
        # https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document
        return result.document

    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error processing document: {e}")

# Call the function
process_document_custom_extractor_sample(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version_id, file_path, mime_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the steps on the guide [Create a Custom Document Extractor in the Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor) and created a schema for the processor, then you don't need to specify a schema when making a processing request in your code.

The code sample you are using is for a Generative AI Custom Extractor that doesn't have a schema created.

[https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#cde:~:text=If%20you%20are,the%20extracted%20entities%3A](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#cde:%7E:text=If%20you%20are,the%20extracted%20entities%3A)

> If you are using a custom model or created a processor version using a foundation model, then use the entity extraction code samples.
>
> The following code sample demonstrates how to configure specific entities for a foundation model Custom Document Extractor on a per-request basis and print the extracted entities:

Try using this code sample instead: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#entity-extraction-code-samples

Also, be sure that you're using the latest version of the [Document AI Python client library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-documentai/).

Comment: Today I have created new Custom extractor. 3 months ago, I could get visual_elements array in API response. Now in new Custom extractor, I cannot see  any checkbox the visual_elements array. The array is empty for new Custom extractor. How can I get checkbox information for new Custom extractor?